# Fibbonacci sequence

Tags: java

I'm having a little troubling understanding the code below. I've worked out the vales for each of the variables for each loop and I understand how the values for each variable change after each loop but I'm confused about how int a = b; represents the sum of the two previous values. I was stuck on this problem for a long time and solved the problem only through trial and error.

I really don't understand how int a = b; represents the sum of the two previous values. I was convinced that since int c = a + b; sums both variable a and variable b that was the variable i wanted to print in my program. Can you explain how int a represents the sum of the two previous values and why int c does not.

```
public class Fibonacci extends ConsoleProgram{
   public void run(){
   int i = 0; 
   int a = 0;
   int b = 1; 

   while ( i <= 12) {

     println(a);
     i++;
     int c = a + b; 
     a = b; 
     b = c; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you *certain* this is your full code? There seem to be things missing: `c` is undefined, `i` is never incremented, and you are right, there is no summing. This program, quite simply, will not compile.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly posted a draft of my question that was incomplete. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to think of it as a staircase:

```
    0
0 + 1 = 1
    1 + 1 = 2
        1 + 2 = 3
            2 + 3 = 5
                3 + 5 = 8
                    5 + 8 = 13
```

An arbitrary step would look like:

```
a + b = c
    b + c = d
```

After the one step, `c` acts like `b` and `b` acts like `a`. But what about `a` and `d`? Since your solution is iterative, you just say that `a` becomes `d` and repeat the process again in a loop:

```
a + b = c
|   b + c = a
|___________|
```

Or in code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 0;

while (true) {
    c = a + b;  // `a + b = c` isn't valid, so you have to flip it around.
    a = b;      // `b` "becomes" `a`
    b = c;      // `c` "becomes" `b`
    c = a;      //  You don't need this step because `c` is just a temp variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's very interesting. Your answer has really helped me understand the part of the problem i was having the most trouble with.

Answer (score 4):

So what happens in this program is:

a = 0, b = 1

c is set to their sum, = 1

a is set to b, = 1

b is set to c, = 1

a = 1, b = 1

c is set to their sum, = 2

a is set to b, = 1

b is set to c, = 2

a = 1, b = 2

c is set to their sum, = 3

a is set to b, = 2

b is set to c, = 3

a = 2, b = 3

c is set to their sum, = 5

a is set to b, = 3

b is set to c, = 5

a = 3, b = 5

... And so on. You should get the idea :)